# How to document and export a constant made with a Rcpp function?

Tags: r, r-package, roxygen2

I have a **Rcpp** function `lazyNA` without argument. I want to have its value in my package, so I need to export it and I want to document it too, using **roxygen2**.

I tried:

```r
#' @name NA_lazy_
#' @title The missing lazy value.
makeActiveBinding("NA_lazy_", lazyNA, .GlobalEnv)
```

I get an help page but without **Usage** section, and `NA_lazy_` is not exported, it is not found after I load the package.

Comment: I don't understand. A function is not a value. Where are you calling the function?

Comment: @Roland `makeActiveBinding` calls `lazyNA()` and stores the result in `NA_lazy_`. When I say the "value" of the function, I mean its returned value.

Comment: OK. Why are you messing with the global environment? You should never do that from within a package. I have never used `makeActiveBinding` but you should try to put it into the package namespace. Also, I don't see you using the `@export` tag.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent  How about removing the `Rcpp` tag?  For once, this question has nothing to do with `Rcpp` but is mostly about mucking with `NAMESPACE` and (delayed) (global) assignment in R, no?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel You're right. I removed it. I was lost.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but not sure it is the best.

```r
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
  lazyna <- function() {
    new("lazyVector", xptr = lazyNA(), length = 1L)
  }
  makeActiveBinding("NA_lazy_", lazyna, parent.env(environment()))
  invisible()
}

#' @name NA_lazy_
#' @title The missing lazy value.
#' @export
"NA_lazy_"
```

Maybe I can use `assign` instead of `makeActiveBinding`? Going to try...

---

## EDIT

With `assign`:

```r
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
  assign(
    "NA_lazy_", 
    new("lazyVector", xptr = lazyNA(), length = 1L),
    envir = parent.env(environment())
  )
  invisible()
}
```