# How to set global package variables so they can be accessed by examples in R CMD check?

Tags: r, devtools, r-package

I am working on an R package right now that includes example images that can be used. I want to set it up so the paths to those images are stored in a global variable that can be accessed either by loading the package or by using something like `myPackage::myVar`.

Currently, I have the images in the `inst/media` folder and set variables containing their paths in the `.onLoad` function in my `zzz.R` file; the function looks like this:

```
.onLoad = function(libname, pkgname) {
    dog = system.file("media", "dog.png", package="myPackage")
    assign("dog", dog, envir=parent.env(environment()))
}
```

When I load my package with `devtools::load_all()`, I can access the variable with just `dog`. However, when I build with `devtools::build()` and install manually, I can only access the variable with `myPackage:::dog`.

Further, I have an example in my man pages generated with roxygen that uses the following code:

```
ret = parsePath(dog)
```

When I run `devtools::check()` it returns an error with this warning saying `Error : object dog not found`.

Is there any way that I can add this global variable in a way that allows me to access them by loading the package and typing the name, and allows the examples to run without error during R CMD check?

Comment: Why don't you use a `rda` data file instead? I'm not sure to understand.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Is there a way that I could create an `rda` file that contains paths in the package? My issue is that I want `dog` to reference the path to an image that is provided with the package, no matter where it is installed.

Comment: Ah no sorry, I missed this point. But I'm surprised the `.onLoad` way does not work. What if you replace `"myPackage"` with the argument `pkgname`?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Unfortunately it still doesn't work the way I would like. When building and installing my package then loading it with `library(myPackage)`, the `dog` variable is still only accessible with `myPackage:::dog`.

Comment: You have to export it, as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74461859/1100107

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Thank you very much - that works perfectly! I was previously trying to export it using `dog` instead of `"dog"`. I will post an answer to this question when I have a second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that while the `dog` variable was being assigned to the environment, it was not being exported by the package; the solution is to export the variable as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74461859/1100107).

The variable is first assigned to the environment with the `.onLoad` function:

```
.onLoad = function(libname, pkgname) {
    dog = system.file("media", "dog.png", package=pkgname)
    assign("dog", dog, envir=parent.env(environment()))
}
```

Then in a separate file, the variable is exported in quotes like such:

```
#' @name dog
#' @title The path to an image of a Dog
#' @export
"dog"
```

I also had to manually add `export(dog)` to the NAMESPACE file before roxygen did it automatically for me. This allows the variable to be accessed by `myPackage::dog`. Without exporting the variable in quotes, the variable could only be accessed with `myPackage:::dog` and would not be seen by other functions using just `dog`. This also passes `devtools::check`.